# R censusapi function introduces NAs

Tags: r

I am using R's censusapi package to download data from the US Census Bureau's Economic Census, specifically for 2012. Some of the columns read into R with NAs introduced by coercion, apparently because R assumes a data type that's inappropriate. In short, how do you integrate a getCensus API call with designated variable types?

Specifically, the variables "NAICS2012_TTL" and some cases of "NAICS2012" read in as NA, and shouldn't. The first is entirely a text field which R insists should be numeric. The second is a series of numbers that should be treated as text, and includes some cases of hyphenated numbers, which read in as NA. How can I tell R to fetch this data and not give it an inappropriate data type? Code follows. You'll need a Census API key to test:

```
library("censusapi")
myFile<-getCensus(name="ewks",vintage=2012,key=("YOURKEYHERE"),
              vars = c("EMP","EMP_F","EMP_S","ESTAB","ESTAB_F","GEO_ID","GEO_TTL","GEOTYPE","NAICS2012","NAICS2012_TTL","OPTAX","PAYANN","PAYANN_F","PLACE"),region="place:*", regionin="state:01")
```

I have tried making myFile as a data.frame and specifying colClasses in the process, unsuccessfully. I have also read every support doc for the censusapi package I can find, to no avail.

Comment: Hack-R, you were right that the C was a typo, however it was a function of creating the post, and was not in my actual code. I've edited the post so it is lower case. It was not the cause of the problem, at any rate.

Comment: I started to work on the actual problem but I was unclear on the desired result so I ended up moving on. But I think you may need to edit the source of the API wrapper library to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of trial and error, I've concluded that the censusapi package is much better suited to the ACS data, and simply does not work well for the Economic Census data. To be clear, the Economic Census data is a Census Bureau data set that is supported by an API. However, the censusapi package converts some fields to NA for Economic Census data.

To more successfully read the Economic Census into R using its API, I turned to using the "curl" and "jsonlite" packages instead. Here is the script that worked. This is written to download NAICS code 22 data for all places. You use could an apply function to loop over the other NAICS codes.

```
library(curl)
library(jsonlite)
curl_download("https://api.census.gov/data/2012/ewks?get=EMP,NAICS2012_TTL,OPTAX,ESTAB,PAYANN,RCPTOT,GEO_TTL&for=place:*&NAICS2012=22      &key=YOURKEYHERE",naics_22)
mymatrix <- fromJSON(naics_22)
matrix2<-data.frame(mymatrix)
write.csv(matrix2,"EC22.csv")
```